# Load dynamic content to a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I receive some data after an AJAX call and I populate a list.

But when an item is clicked from that list, I want to show a modal with information about that item (like a picture, how popular it is - how many times it was clicked -, author etc). I can do this in an ugly way:

```
$('#target').append(
    $('<div class = "col-md-4" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#myModal" onClick = someFunction(' + someArgument + ')>' + someText + '</div>' +
      '<div class = "modal fade" id = "myModal" role = "dialog">' + '<div class = "modal-dialog modal-lg">' +
      '<div class = "modal-content"> <div class = "modal-header"> <h4 class = "modal-title">' + someTitle + '</h4></div>' +
      '<div class = "modal-body">Description: ' + description + ' Author: ' + author + '<br</br>' +
      '<img src = "' + imgSource + '" class = "modal-dialog modal-lg" style = "max-width: 25%;">' +
      '<button type = "button" class = "close" data-dismiss = "modal" id = "myModal">&times;</button>' +
      '<div class = "modal-footer"></div></div></div></div></div>'));
```

This is ugly, error prone, hard to maintain, hard to read. Can it be done in a more elegant manner?

Answer (score 1):

- Firstly, your code should be written inside `show.bs.modal` function.

  ```
  $('#target').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // do something...
  })
  ```

See this:   http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

- Second, I prefer to use jQuery to create DOM elements, like this

  ```
  $("<div>").addClass("col-md-4").attr("data-target","#myModal").append(
  $("<div>").addClass("modal fade")//add more here
  );
  ```

Comment: This seems to makes things more elegant and easier to read. Thanks.